# How to extract IP address from Spatie\Dns\Records\A object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dns, ip

I'm working with Laravel and [Spatie DNS Retriever](https://github.com/spatie/dns) to get the ip address from a domain name.

This is my Controller method:

```
public function getDomainInfo($domain)
    {
        $dns = new Dns();
        $recordsA = $dns->getRecords($domain, ['A', 'CNAME']);

        // dd($recordsA);

        $ip = $recordsA[0]->ip;
        dd($ip);

        return view('client.domain', compact('records','recordsA','recordsMX','recordsMX','recordsAll'));
    }
```

And I get this error:

**Cannot access protected property Spatie\Dns\Records\A::$ip**

However results of `dd($recordsA)` shows this as output:

```
array:1 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/Client/IpInfoController.php:43
  0 => Spatie\Dns\Records\A {#294 ▼
    #host: "google.com"
    #ttl: 418
    #class: "IN"
    #type: "A"
    #ip: "216.239.38.120"
  }
]
```

So what's going wrong here? How can get the ip value in this case?

I also tried getting the ip value like this but didn't work out:

`dd($recordsA[0]['ip']);`

And returns this error:

**Cannot use object of type Spatie\Dns\Records\A as array**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array:1 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/Client/IpInfoController.php:43
  0 => Spatie\Dns\Records\A {#294 ▼
    #host: "google.com"
    #ttl: 418
    #class: "IN"
    #type: "A"
    #ip: "216.239.38.120"
  }
]
```

You can get this by calling as a function for example:

```
public function getDomainInfo($domain)
{
   $dns = new Dns();
   $recordsA = $dns->getRecords($domain, ['A', 'CNAME']);
   
   $ip = $recordsA[0]->ip();
   $host = $recordsA[0]->host();
   dd($ip, $host);

   return view('client.domain', compact('records','recordsA','recordsMX','recordsMX','recordsAll'));
}
```